# Number of Query mobile elements (select controls) doesn't add up

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

When looping through all the form elements on my jQuery mobile page by their class I'm seeing lots of extra elements that don't have IDs. This isn't a major issue with a few controls, but with lots of selects on a page presumably there's lots of wasted code, where the code inside the loop runs for no reason.

E.g. a jQuery mobile page with a single select control like this:

```
<select name="myName" id="myId" class="myClass"/></select>
```

...and a javascript loop that looks like this:

```
for(g=0;g<$('.myClass').length;g++){
  alert(g + " - " + $('.myClass')[g].id);
}
```

...produces two alerts:

- 0 -
- 1 - myId

Anyone know why there are two elements and why the first one doesn't have an ID? It seems to be something to do with jQuery Mobile creating a new fancy control in addition to the original 'standard' one.

If this is the case what could I use for my selector so that I only select the actual visible select control?

Comment: why wouldn't you look through the elements using `.each()`?

Comment: This too produces two elements - one with no id and the second with teh correct id (myId) (so doesn't help unfortunately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through them like so:

```
$("select.myClass").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This will output the ID of each element with the class `myClass`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ypWss/2/

Comment: This too produces two elements - one with no id and the second with the correct id (myId) (so doesn't help unfortunately).

Comment: Mind showing me? I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F42nz/ and it works fine?

Comment: My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ypWss/1/ uses jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1 whereas yours uses jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 - not sure why this should affect it.

Comment: Fixed the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypWss/2/ .. Not sure why it was adding those extra elements, fixed when I changed the selector to `$("select.myClass")`. Also fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way, using `$.each()`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/y79JW/)**

```
// Find all selects with .myClass
var list = $(document).find('select.myClass');

// Read the result
$.each(list, function () {
 console.log($(this).attr('name')+' : '+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

---

You can push them into an Array.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vkkxW/)**

```
// Create an Array
var selects = [];

// Find all selects with .myClass
var list = $(document).find('select.myClass');

// Push id of each select
if (list.length > 0) {
 $.each(list, function () {
  selects.push({
   'id': $(this).attr('id')
  });
 });
}

// Read the array
$.each(selects, function (i, v) {
 console.log(v.id);
});
```